# How can I use lettuce in my Django project, within Eclipse?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev, lettuce

I'm following the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro) for Django v1.6, and running it inside eclipse with PyDev. I got to the page on testing and I thought I'd mix it up (read: Run before I can walk) and learn Lettuce as well.

From what I've read online lettuce should be bundled with PyDev by default. which makes sense as the line `from lettuce import *` does not error in my steps.py, but the rest of the code does:

```py
from lettuce import *

@step('Given my poll is (\d+) days in the future')
def have_future_poll(step, number):
    world.number = int(number)
```

The error for the `@step` is:

> Undefined variable: step
>   step Found at: polls.tests.features.steps
>
> step

And for world is:

> Undefined variable: world

So I don't think it's importing properly.

How should I use Lettuce in eclipse?

Comment: Have you put that file in a directory called features?

Comment: @RobertGrant Yeah I have a dir called features. Does it need to be top level?

Comment: Does it works when you do specific import instead of wildcard import ?

Answer (score 2):

To use `lattuce.world` try to import `world` explicit: `from lattuce import world` should work then - I experienced that phenomenon with other apps like logicaldelete, too. But I can't tell why it does not work the way you did...

To use `@step` you should import that function/file/app `step(..)` as well: `from polls.tests.features import steps`. Otherwise there is no methode named `step(..)` defined within your .py-file and `@step` becomes a decorator of a non-existing method.

Comment: You should check if your lettuce library is up to date, the `__all__` list in the `__init__` module contains world: https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/blob/master/lettuce/__init__.py#L60 some old versions didn't had it: https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/blob/3a4d9693d1d14a8bdb8230b39ac44b0814c61233/lettuce/__init__.py#L29